# Python list comprehension understanding

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I wrote some code with help and I am trying to understand what a specific line means:

```
rec = [f[0:-2] for f in List if f[-1] == i][0]
```

I understand this is s a list comprehension that takes the values in the list, minus the last 2 when equal to another variable i.

What does the `[0]` do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an inefficient way to grab the first filtered element from the resulting list object.

```
[f[0:-2] for f in List if f[-1] == i]
```

is the list comprehension, producing a new list object. That object is then indexed with `[0]` to get the first value.

You could rewrite it to:

```
tmp = [f[0:-2] for f in List if f[-1] == i]
rec = tmp[0]
del tmp
```

and get the same result.

The efficient method would be to use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
rec = next(f[:-2] for f in List if f[-1] == i)
```

This only iterates over `List` until the first `f` is found that matches the test, instead of first producing *all* such matches, then discard the list object again.

Comment: Thank you that was very well explained. I should have mentioned that this is part of a for loop that is iterating over another list so probably more efficient than I described. Thanks again.